# Ввести порядковый нoмер игральной карты от(0 до 35) и определить масть и достоинство карты(не надо писать 36 if или switch)

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, if, switch

Написала с 36 свитчами,нельзя использовать цикл и тд.Нужно ограничаться ифами и свитчами,буду рада помощи

```
#include<iostream>;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Select a number of card:";
    cin >> a;
    if (a >= 1 && a <= 9) {
        cout << "Diamonds" << endl;
        switch (a) {

        case 1:
            cout << "Ace of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "King of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Queen of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Jack of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Ten of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "Nine of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 7:
            cout << "Eight of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 8:
            cout << "Seven of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        case 9:
            cout << "Six of diamonds" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (a > 9 && a <= 18) {
        cout << "Clubs" << endl;

        switch (a) {
        case 10:
            cout << "   Ace of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        case 11:
            cout << "King of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        case 12:
            cout << "Queen of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        case 13:
            cout << "Jack of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        case 14:
            cout << "Ten of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        case 15:
            cout << "Nine of clubs" << endl;
        case 16:
            cout << "Eight of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        case 17:
            cout << "Seven of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        case 18:
            cout << "Six of clubs" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (a > 18 && a <= 27) {
        cout << "Hearts" << endl;
        switch (a) {
        case 19:
            cout << "   Ace of hearts" << endl;
            break;
        case 20:
            cout << "King of hearts" << endl;
            break;
        case 21:
            cout << "Queen of hearts" << endl;
            break;
        case 22:
            cout << "Jack of hearts" << endl;
            break;
        case 23:
            cout << "Ten of hearts" << endl;
            break;
        case 24:
            cout << "Nine of hearts" << endl;
        case 25:
            cout << "Eight of hearts" << endl;
            break;
        case 26:
            cout << "Seven of hearts" << endl;
            break;
        case 27:
            cout << "Six of hearts" << endl;
            break;

        }
    }
    else if (a > 27 && a <= 36) {
        cout << "Spades" << endl;
        switch (a) {
        case 28:
            cout << "   Ace of speads" << endl;
            break;
        case 29:
            cout << "King of speads" << endl;
            break;
        case 30:
            cout << "Queen of speads" << endl;
            break;
        case 31:
            cout << "Jack of speadss" << endl;
            break;
        case 32:
            cout << "Ten of speads" << endl;
            break;
        case 33:
            cout << "Nine of speads" << endl;
        case 34:
            cout << "Eight of speads" << endl;
            break;
        case 35:
            cout << "Seven of speads" << endl;
            break;
        case 36:
            cout << "Six of speads" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `x%4` и `x/4` например так. Ну или `x/9` и `x%9` смотря какой порядок карт в этих 36.

Comment: Порядок хаотичен

Comment: @УлькерГасанова Если порядок хаотичен, то как Вы можете определить какая карта имеет номер, например, 17? Определить карту по номеру можно только в том случае, если известен порядок расположения карт.

Comment: Извиняюсь .не ясно выразилась,порядок кард вводим сами в cout в свитчах,имела ввиду в условии не задается порядок

Comment: Я не особо поняла x%4 как тут применить

Comment: А покажите ваш код. Даже интересно... Ну, а мы его уже перепишем.

Comment: Я написала внизу

Comment: "Внизу" не надо писать код, внизу предназначено для решений вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отлично. Итак, карты идут так: масть

```
diamonds      1- 9     0
clubs        10-18     1
hearts       19-27     2 
speads       28-36     3
```

Т.е. номер масти (самая правая колонка) получается из номера карты как

```
(a-1)/9
```

Теперь посмотрим на достоинство

```
Ace       0
King      1
Queen     2
...
Six       8
```

Получить его можно как `(a-1)%9`.

Итак,

```
const char * suit[] = {"diamonds","clubs","hearts","speads" };
const char * vals[] = { "Ace", "King", "Queen","Jack", "Ten", "Nine",
                        "Eight","Seven","Six" };

....
cout << vals[(a-1)%9] << " of " << suit[(a-1)/9] << endl;
```

Примерно так (не компилировал, писал прямо в ответ...)

Ничего страшного, что ни одного `if` вообще не понадобилось? :)

Comment: Не компилировал, но имху именно так выглядит правильное направление: массив мастей и массив карт. Рекомендую ответ на галку.

Comment: Сделала просто /9 для мастей и %9 для количества.Это тоже рабочий метод.спасибо!

Comment: У вас в коде - **`a` начинается с 1**, потому мне и пришлось сначала вычитать эту единицу. Конечно, с нуля проще и лучше, но учтите, что карты 36 у вас в этом случае нет! :)